# Unable to acquire lock on the view to recompile it

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Created a view VW on base tables A and B. There is an ETL process which loads data into T_A and T_B. After data loading is complete, the job triggers rename procedure. This procedure renames T_A as A and table A is renamed as T_A. Similarly T_B table is renamed as B and table B is renamed to T_B.

When this renaming happens the view is becoming invalid and to make it valid have to compile it again.

To fix this, added view compilation statement at the end in rename procedure. It works fine but the problem is let's say user A is accessing the view data and at the same time my rename procedure is triggered. Now the rename procedure is not able to compile the view as long as user A is accessing the view.

Please share your thoughts on how to overcome this problem.

Dex.

Answer (score 0):

While dependant `view` is invalidated when a change is made to the underlying `table`, Oracle will automatically recompile the `view` when it is accessed.

So in your example, `VW` is **INVALID** when `Table A` is dropped,
it is still **INVALID** when `T_A` is renamed to `A`, but as soon as someone queries the `view`, it is automatically recompiled, the query works correctly, and the `view` becomes **VALID**.

So there is no need to explicitly recompile your `views` in your script.

Comment: No thats not the case...the view is not getting automatically compiled when someone is querying it...its running forever

Comment: @Dex that's  strange - because I tested the above scenario on `11g` before posting... do `T_A` and `A` have exactly the same structure? What I have tried was dropping a `table`, recreating the same `table` - and the behavior of the `view` is the one I have described....

Comment: @Dex actually the way you describe it ... it seems that oracle tries to recompile the view ... but it is waiting for view to be unlocked  first... and you wait forever.. is there something that could be causing this initial  lock?

Comment: In my case am not dropping the tables...Renaming the _T to _A, the structure of the tables is same but the indexes are different

Comment: @Dex Could you try renaming `A` to `A_old` (this action should invalidate the `view`), then renaming `A_old` back to `A` (as it was before - so structure and indexes all are the same) and then check if the query hangs (without explicitly compiling the view)?